# C++ Expected class-name before '{' token. Inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I've been googling and reading about this and didn't come up with an answer yet, maybe someone can help me with this.

I want my UserPile class to be able to access data members and class member functions from my CardPile class.  I keep getting the error mention in the title.  Could someone explain what is happening?  The inheritance tutorials I have seen look just like my code except mine is multiple source code files.

```
//CardPile.h
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Card;
class CardPile
{
   protected:
       vector<Card> thePile;
       //Card thePile[];
       int pileSize;
   public:
       CardPile();
       void insertCard( Card );
       Card accessCard( int);  
       void displayPile();
       void shuffle(); //shuffle the pile
       void initializeDeck(); //create deck of cards

       void deal(CardPile &, CardPile &);
       void showHand();
       bool checkForAce();
       void discard(CardPile);
       void drawCard(CardPile &);

 };

    //UserPlayer.h
 using namespace std;



class UserPlayer: public CardPile
{
    private:
        //CardPile userPile;                          
    public:
        UserPlayer(); 

};

//UserPlayer.cpp

#include "UserPlayer.h"
#include "CardPile.h"


UserPlayer::UserPlayer()
{

}
```

I don't have anything happening in this UserPlayer class yet, because I will be using functions from the base class, so I want to at least see it compile before I start writing it.

Thanks for anyone's help.

Comment: Please don't reedit to broken markup...

Comment: @gf, you and me edit the question at same time, submitted at 6 second diff, but SO didn't informed as its already edit, but just got submitted, I found your is better, and I roll it back to your revision, but OP edited again to best one, so it should be ok now.

Comment: Ah, ok. These *some-second-diffs* are sometimes strange.

Comment: A side-note: you shouldn't use `using namespace std;` in header files, because that pulls in the whole std namespace for every file that includes your header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to include `CardPile.h` in `UserPlayer.h` if you want to use the class `CardPile` there.

You are also missing include guards in the headers, e.g.:

```
// CardPile.h:
#ifndef CARDPILE_H
#define CARDPILE_H

class CardPile {
    // ...
};

#endif
```

Without this you are effectively including `CardPile.h` twice in `UserPlayer.cpp` - once from `UserPlayer.h` and once via the line `#include "CardPile.h"`

Comment: When I do that I get a redefinition of class 'CardPile' error

Comment: You are missing include guards, added that.

Comment: this gives me the error "unterminated #ifndef"

I just add it to the top of CardPile, right?

Comment: Did you also add the `#endif` to the end of `CardPile.h`?  ... See e.g. here for what include guards are: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: Thank you, I did not see the #endif and have not learned about include guards yet.  This works now.

Answer (score 1):

UserPlayer.h needs to #include CardPile.h -- is that the case with your code?